# How to remove a video element using a media query

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I have a video that automatically plays when the window loads. But now that I am doing the mobile version, I would like to remove it. Using display:none in my mobile query  removes the element but the video still plays in the background. I have a script in my html which controls the video fade in and out and I thought about just adding an if else statement using the window width but to no luck. The element removes but the video still plays in the background. Any guidance on this will be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

    if($(window).width()<761){
        $('video').get(0).pause();
        $('#intro').remove();
    }
    else{

    $('#intro').fadeIn(10000, function() {
    });

    $('video').bind('ended', function(){

        $('#intro').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        });
     });

     $('button').click(function() {
                $('video').get(0).pause();
                $('#intro').css('display', 'none');

     });
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried actually removing the element from the DOM:

```
if($(window).width()<761){
        $('video').get(0).pause();
        $('#intro').remove();
    }
```

You could also append the markup for the video conditionally using Javascript. So omit the video from the markup and add the following Javascript, obviously this will need to be customized for your video.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    if($(window).width()<761){
        $('video').get(0).pause();
        $('#intro').remove();
    }
    else{
    //only add markup when screen size is large enough
    $(document).append('<video style="display:none" width="320" height="240" controls><source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"><\/video>');

    $('#intro').fadeIn(10000, function() {
    });

    $('video').bind('ended', function(){

        $('#intro').fadeOut(5000, function() {
        });
     });

     $('button').click(function() {
                $('video').get(0).pause();
                $('#intro').css('display', 'none');

     });
});
}
```

Comment: Yup. Tried that also to no avail. The element is removed but the darn video keeps playing in the background. I think the if/else statement is wrong also because the same thing happens when I increase the screen size to 100% width. When I remove the if/else statement my script goes back to working correctly but still has mobile dilema.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I appreciate your help. I feel stupid and I'm sorry for wasting your time but my last "else" brace is the last line in the script and it should be the second to last. It's working fine now.

Comment: @Addy75 Good catch. I see what you mean.